# Vue "Is not a function" problem in my todolist app

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I have a todo app and when I click in certain item it should be marked as completed.

I'm importing items from Firebase but when I click the item I get the error:

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: todo.toggleChecked is not a function"

I'm newbie with firebase and Vue so I don't know what's happening.

Heres is my code:

```
TodoList.vue

<template>
  <div class="todolist">
    <h3>TodoList</h3>
    <b-input-group class="mt-3">
      <b-form-input
        v-model="todoInput"
        placeholder="Agregar tarea"
        aria-describedby="Agregar tarea"
      ></b-form-input>
      <b-input-group-append>
        <b-button variant="primary" @click="agregarTodo()">Agregar</b-button>
      </b-input-group-append>
    </b-input-group>
    <b-list-group>
      <b-list-group-item
        v-for="(todo, index) in todoList"
        :key="index"
        class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mt-3"
        :variant="listItemStyle(todo.checked)"
        @click="todo.toggleChecked()"
      >
        {{ todo.todo }}
        <b-button variant="outline-dark" @click.stop="eliminarTodo(todo)" pill
          ><font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-trash"
        /></b-button>
      </b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { Todo } from "@/types/Todo";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faTrash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  collection,
  Firestore,
  getDocs,
  getFirestore,
  addDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseConfig from "@/firebaseConfig";

library.add(faTrash);
Vue.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon);

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

@Component
export default class TodoList extends Vue {
  todoInput: string = "";
  todoList: Todo[] = [];

  listItemStyle(isChecked: boolean) {
    return isChecked ? "success" : "";
  }

  agregarTodo() {
    //console.log("addTodo: " + this.todoInput);
    let todo = new Todo(this.todoInput);
    this.todoList.push(todo);

    async function addTodo(db: Firestore) {
      const todoCol = collection(db, "todolist");
      await addDoc(todoCol, { todo: todo.todo, checked: todo.checked });
    }

    addTodo(db).then((data) => {
      console.log("Agregado?");
    });
  }

  eliminarTodo(todo: Todo) {
    console.log("delTodo: " + todo);
    this.todoList = this.todoList.filter((todoItem) => {
      return todoItem !== todo;
    });
  }

  mounted() {
    async function getTodo(db: Firestore) {
      const todoCol = collection(db, "todolist");
      const todoSnapshot = await getDocs(todoCol);
      const todoList = todoSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      return todoList as Todo[];
    }

    getTodo(db).then((data) => {
      this.todoList = data;
    });
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.list-group-item-success {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
</style>
```

```
Todo.ts
export class Todo {
    todo: string;
    checked: boolean;

    constructor(todo: string){
        this.todo = todo;
        this.checked = false;
    }

    toggleChecked(){
        this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
}
```

Also, I'm having a little trouble finding documentation with this syntax-style because most tutorials uses something like:

```
app
   .firebase()
   .collection('collectionName')
   .add(itemToAdd)
   .then((result) => { moreCode })
```

But it doesn't work with my project for some reason

EDIT:
I solved it using this syntax to get the values from the Firestore

```
async function getTodo(db: Firestore) {
      const todoCol = collection(db, "todolist");
      const todoSnapshot = await getDocs(todoCol);
      const todoList = todoSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        let docTodo = new Todo(doc.data()['todo']);
        docTodo.checked = doc.data()['checked'];
        return docTodo;
      });
      return todoList as Todo[];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the items that you get from the database in `mounted` are not instances of `Todo` class. Although you return them with `todoList as Todo[]`, they are just raw data. These objects won't have the `toggleChecked` method defined on them.

You could create `Todo` type objects from the retrieved data with something like this:

```
async function getTodo(db: Firestore) {
    // ...
    const todoList = todoSnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        // pass 'todo' and 'checked' properties from doc to Todo
        return new Todo(doc.todo, doc.checked); 
    }

    return todoList as Todo[];
}
```

Comment: If I do it like that I get `undefined` data

Comment: Looks like I have to use `data()['propertyName']` syntax. I can't find anyone using that syntax.`